# transfering managers commands into employees, using SQL commands groupby and having

Tags: sql, group-by

EMPLOYEE (fname, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)
KEY: ssn

DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
KEY: dnumber.

PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)
KEY: pnumber.

WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)
KEY: (essn, pno)

DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)
KEY: (essn, dependent-name)

I want to find last name of employees who work on 3 or more projects, use group by and having in a correlated subquery.

I've done a similar problem in finding manager before but now I want to find employee, I tried to transform the code, here is what I have:

anything I should change?

```
SELECT Lname
FROM   Employee       e,
       Department     d
WHERE  (e.ssn = d.mgrssn)
       AND e.ssn IN (SELECT w.essn
                     FROM   works_on     w,
                            Project      p
                     WHERE  w.pno = p.pnumber
                     GROUP BY
                            w.essn
                     HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your query as follows.

```
select Lname
  from Employee e
where e.ssn in (
                  select  w.essn
                   from   works_on w, Project p
                  where w.pno = p.pnumber
                  group by w.essn
                  having count(*) >= 3
                 )
```

Comment: should lname be changed e.lname?

Comment: it is not required as you will be having only one instance of lname. Though you can have it

Comment: Thank you! and lastly w.pno = p.pnumber is must have because it tells you which employee worked on which projects?